# Matplotlib Pyplot breaks on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, ubuntu-16.04

I am currently using Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 16.04 and would like the ability to plot figures using Matplotlib. However, calling any sort of plot command causes the entire script to hang at that line.

** Note ** Before marking this as a duplicate question, please consider that this issue may not be related to the backend that I am using as I have tried every iteration of this solution that I have found on the internet.

A simple script which illustrates my problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.interactive('True')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    print 'Hello World!'
    plt.figure()
    print 'Hello Again World!'
```

The output of the above script is: Hello World!

The script then hangs at the plt.figure() line, causes 100% cpu  usage, and cannot be killed using Ctrl-C. I use "kill" to kill that process.

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem. The script works as expected and eventually ends. I tried it in Ubuntu 16.04 with matplotlib 1.5.1. Which version of matplotlib are you using? (you can get it with matplotlib.__version__

Comment: No one in my lab can reproduce my problem either haha. You raise an interesting point though: >>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.__version__
'0+unknown'

Comment: I fixed the version issue, not my version is 1.5.1. However, I have the same original problem :(

Comment: Maybe there is some problem with the custom install of Python 2.7 (default Ubuntu 16.04 comes only with Python 3.5.1 as `python3`) and the matplotlib installation. Have you tried to create a virtual environment and install matplotlib there (or reinstall matplotlib if you don't care)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never figured out what caused my problem, but my (poor) solution was to reinstall Ubuntu 16.04 and then matplotlib. It is working fine now.

Thanks everyone!